# Why getting Hadoop Startup SafemodeException

Tags: hadoop

We have a setup of *hadoop* cluster with three nodes. When we start the cluster, we have an error message like

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname master:
```

But in our application nowhere using that name in configs.
But the daemons all running in master and slave as well. But while checking the UI, only one node is live node. 
Can anyone help me where these conf file refers.

Comment: What are the contents of your `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/masters` and `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/slaves` files?

Answer (score 0):

May be, you have written "master:" instead of "master" to files $HADOOP_HOME/conf/masters | $HADOOP_HOME/conf/slaves...

This is a dns problem, you can encounter lots of dns problems during environment setup. You can use hadoop-dns-checker tool to figure out the problems...

Comment: I do see the exception in hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-MasterNode.log as below," problem cleaning system directory: hdfs://masternode:54310/mnt/sdb1/mapred/system
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /mnt/sdb1/mapred/system. Name node is in safe mode." Can anyone help pls.

Answer (score 0):

did you write the `conf/masters` and `conf/slaves file`? In your hadoop folder, do this:

```
echo localhost > conf/masters;
echo localhost > conf/slaves;
```

Also, In `conf/core-site.xml`, make sure you set `fs.default.name`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

In `conf/mapred-site.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9001</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.socket.write.timeout</name>
    <value>0</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```